# JSP page is not refreshing

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, jstl

I'm sending a map of list to my jsp page by spring controller, in jsp I'm using jstl tags for populate the data and performing some hide and show table operations using jquery,  I have two date fields and one go button, when I'm selecting the date and hitting go button, new data is coming from back end but not reflecting to jsp.

this is my Spring controller method which is returning map of list:

```
@RequestMapping(value=OMSConstant.IBDQ,method={RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
    public @ResponseBody ModelAndView populateIBDQAggregate(@RequestParam(value="startDate",required=false)String startDate,@RequestParam(value="endDate",required=false)String endDate,@RequestParam(value="reportType",required=false)String reportType,@ModelAttribute("ibdq")IBDQAggregateAndBreakout ibdqAggregate,ModelMap model){

        HashMap<String, ArrayList> dataList=null;

        dataList=(HashMap<String, ArrayList>) ibdqService.getIBDQData(startDate,endDate,reportType);

        model.put("dataList", dataList);
        return new ModelAndView(OMSConstant.IBDQ_PAGE,model);
    }
```

---

this is my ajax function:

```
function getIBDQData(){
        $("#loading").show();
        $(document).ready(function() {


                $.ajax({
                    method : 'POST',
                    url : 'ibdq.htm?startDate='+$('#startDate').val()+'&endDate='+$('#endDate').val()+'&reportType='+$("input[name='optradio']:checked").val(),
                    success : function(data) {
                        console.log('data--'+data);


                        $("#loading").hide();
                    }
                });

            });

        }
```

---

hide/show tables using jquery:

$("#breakoutTable").hide();
     $("#breakDQtable").hide();

```
 $("#aggregateList").click(function(){


        $("#breakoutTable").hide();
        $("#breakDQtable").hide();
         $("#aggregateTable").show();
          $("#aggreDQtable").show();
  });

   $("#breakoutList").click(function(){
             $("#aggreDQtable").hide();
         $("#aggregateTable").hide();
        $("#breakoutTable").show();
         $("#breakDQtable").show();
```

### });

and this is my jsp page:

```
<body onload="getIBDQData();">
    <div class="wrapper bgImg">

        <div class="searchCnt formCnt height801 clearfix">
            <div class="container containerIbdq">



                        <label id='l_startDate' style="margin-left: 30px;">Start Date:</label> 
                        <input type="text" id="startDate" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" >

                        <label id='l_endDate' style="margin-bottom: 15px;" >End Date:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="endDate" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">

                        <input type="button" value="Go" name="go" style="margin-bottom: 20px;" onclick="getIBDQData();"/>

                        <label class="radio-inline" style="margin-left :30px; margin-bottom: 10px;" >Aggregate</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="aggregateList" name="optradio" value="A" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" checked="checked" />

                        <label class="radio-inline"  style="margin-bottom: 10px;">Breakout</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="breakoutList" name="optradio" value="B" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" />




                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class=" clearfix insidepage">
            <div class="gridCnt">

<table id="aggregateTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
                    class="grid" width="100%" style="margin-top:-20px;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr style="background-color: silver;">
                            <th style="width:214.5px;">----------------</th>
                            <c:if test="${not empty dataList}">

                                <c:forEach items="${dataList}" var="listValue">
                                    <c:if test="${listValue.key =='aggregateList' }">

                                        <c:forEach items="${listValue.value}" var="listItem">
                                            <th style="width:218px;" ><a href="javascript:void(0)"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="show" id="${listItem.fiscalMonth}">${listItem.fiscalMonth}</a></th>
                                        </c:forEach>

                                    </c:if>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </c:if>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:left;">Total IB Count</td>
                            <c:forEach items="${dataList}" var="listValue">
                                <c:if test="${listValue.key =='aggregateList' }">
                                    <c:forEach items="${listValue.value}" var="listItem">
                                        <td style="text-align:right;" >${listItem.totalIBCount}</td>
                                    </c:forEach>
                                </c:if>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:left;">Total Hardware Count (Active IB)</td>
                            <c:forEach items="${dataList}" var="listValue">
                                <c:if test="${listValue.key =='aggregateList' }">
                                    <c:forEach items="${listValue.value}" var="listItem">
                                        <td style="text-align:right;" >${listItem.totalHWCount}</td>
                                    </c:forEach>
                                </c:if>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:left;">IB DQ % (All Attribute)</td>
                            <c:forEach items="${dataList}" var="listValue">
                                <c:if test="${listValue.key =='aggregateList' }">
                                    <c:forEach items="${listValue.value}" var="listItem">
                                        <td style="text-align:right;" >${listItem.dqPercent}</td>
                                    </c:forEach>
                                </c:if>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:left;">IB DQ % (Top 10 Attribute)</td>

                            <c:forEach items="${dataList}" var="listValue">
                                <c:if test="${listValue.key =='aggregateList' }">
                                    <c:forEach items="${listValue.value}" var="listItem">
                                        <td style="text-align:right;" >${listItem.tomTenAttributeDQPercent}</td>
                                    </c:forEach>
                                </c:if>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </tr>
                        <c:if test="${empty  dataList}">
                            <tr align="center">
                                <font color="red">No Data Found !!!</font></
                            <tr>
                        </c:if>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table id="breakoutTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
                    class="grid" width="100%" style="margin-top:-20px;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr style="background-color: silver;">
                            <th style="width:214.5px;">----------------</th>
                            <c:if test="${not empty dataList}">
                                <c:forEach items="${dataList}" var="listValue">
                                    <c:if test="${listValue.key =='breakoutList' }">
                                        <c:forEach items="${listValue.value}" var="listItem">
                                            <th style="width:218px;" ><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="show" id="${listItem.fiscalMonth}">${listItem.fiscalMonth}</a></th>
                                        </c:forEach>
                                    </c:if>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </c:if>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:left;">Total IB Count</td>
                            <c:forEach items="${dataList}" var="listValue">
                                <c:if test="${listValue.key =='breakoutList' }">
                                    <c:forEach items="${listValue.value}" var="listItem">
                                        <td style="text-align:right;" >${listItem.totalIBCount}</td>
                                    </c:forEach>
                                </c:if>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:left;">Total Hardware Count (Active IB)</td>
                            <c:forEach items="${dataList}" var="listValue">
                                <c:if test="${listValue.key =='breakoutList' }">
                                    <c:forEach items="${listValue.value}" var="listItem">
                                        <td style="text-align:right;" >${listItem.totalHWCount}</td>
                                    </c:forEach>
                                </c:if>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:left;">IB DQ % (All Attribute)</td>
                            <c:forEach items="${dataList}" var="listValue">
                                <c:if test="${listValue.key =='breakoutList' }">
                                    <c:forEach items="${listValue.value}" var="listItem">
                                        <td style="text-align:right;" >${listItem.dqPercent}</td>
                                    </c:forEach>
                                </c:if>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:left;">IB DQ % (Top 10 Attribute)</td>
                            <c:forEach items="${dataList}" var="listValue">
                                <c:if test="${listValue.key =='breakoutList' }">
                                    <c:forEach items="${listValue.value}" var="listItem">
                                        <td style="text-align:right;" >${listItem.tomTenAttributeDQPercent}</td>
                                    </c:forEach>
                                </c:if>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </tr>
                        <c:if test="${empty  dataList}">
                            <tr align="center">
                                <font color="red">No Data Found !!!</font>
                            <tr>
                        </c:if>

                    </tbody>
                </table>

<table id="aggreDQtable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
                    class="grid" width="100%" >
                        <thead>
                        <tr style="background-color: silver;">
                                <th style="width: 200px;text-align:left;" onclick="sortTable(0)">Attribute</th> 
                                <th onclick="sortTable(1)" style="width: 102.5px;">DQ</th>   
                                <th onclick="sortTable(2)" style="width: 102.5px;">QTY</th>  
                                <th onclick="sortTable(3)" style="width: 102.5px;"> DQ</th>  
                                <th onclick="sortTable(4)" style="width: 102.5px;">QTY </th>    
                                <th onclick="sortTable(5)" style="width: 102.5px;">DQ</th>  
                                 <th onclick="sortTable(6)" style="width: 102.5px;">QTY</th>
                                 <th onclick="sortTable(7)" style="width: 102.5px;">DQ</th>
                                 <th onclick="sortTable(8)" style="width: 102.5px;">QTY</th>
                                 <th onclick="sortTable(9)" style="width: 102.5px;">DQ</th>
                                 <th onclick="sortTable(10)" style="width: 102.5px;">QTY</th>    
                                 <th onclick="sortTable(11)" style="width: 102.5px;">DQ</th>    
                                 <th onclick="sortTable(12)" style="width: 102.5px;">QTY </th>   
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <c:if test="${not empty dataList}">
                                <c:forEach items="${dataList}" var="listValue">
                                    <c:if test="${listValue.key =='dqAggrList' }">
                                        <c:forEach items="${listValue.value}" var="listItem">
                                    <tr id="${listItem.attribute}">
                                        <td style="text-align:left;">${listItem.attribute}</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:right;">${listItem.dQ1}</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:right;">${listItem.qty1}</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:right;">${listItem.dQ2}</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:right;">${listItem.qty2}</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:right;">${listItem.dQ3}</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:right;">${listItem.qty3}</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:right;">${listItem.dQ4}</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:right;">${listItem.qty4}</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:right;">${listItem.dQ5}</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:right;">${listItem.qty5}</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:right;">${listItem.dQ6}</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:right;">${listItem.qty6}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                        </c:forEach>
                                    </c:if>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </c:if>
                            <c:if test="${empty  dataList}">
                            <tr align="center">
                                <font color="red">No Data Found !!!</font>
                            <tr>
                        </c:if>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>

                        </table>

<table id="breakDQtable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
                    class="grid" width="100%" >
                        <thead>
                            <tr style="background-color: silver;"  >
                                <th style="width: 200px;text-align:left;"   onclick="sortBreakTable(0)">Attribute</th>  
                                <th  onclick="sortBreakTable(1)" style="width: 102.5px;">DQ</th>     
                                <th  onclick="sortBreakTable(2)" style="width: 102.5px;">QTY</th>    
                                <th  onclick="sortBreakTable(3)" style="width: 102.5px;"> DQ</th>    
                                <th  onclick="sortBreakTable(4)" style="width: 102.5px;">QTY </th>  
                                <th  onclick="sortBreakTable(5)" style="width: 102.5px;">DQ</th>    
                                 <th  onclick="sortBreakTable(6)" style="width: 102.5px;">QTY</th>
                                 <th onclick="sortBreakTable(7)" style="width: 102.5px;">DQ</th>
                                 <th  onclick="sortBreakTable(8)" style="width: 102.5px;">QTY</th>
                                 <th onclick="sortBreakTable(9)" style="width: 102.5px;">DQ</th>
                                 <th onclick="sortBreakTable(10)" style="width: 102.5px;">QTY</th>   
                                 <th  onclick="sortBreakTable(11)" style="width: 102.5px;">DQ</th>  
                                 <th  onclick="sortBreakTable(12)" style="width: 102.5px;">QTY </th>     
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <c:if test="${not empty dataList}">
                                <c:forEach items="${dataList}" var="listValue">
                                    <c:if test="${listValue.key =='dqBreakList' }">
                                        <c:forEach items="${listValue.value}" var="listItem">
                                    <tr  id="${listItem.attribute}">
                                        <td style="text-align:left;">${listItem.attribute}</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:right;">${listItem.dQ1}</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:right;">${listItem.qty1}</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:right;">${listItem.dQ2}</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:right;">${listItem.qty2}</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:right;">${listItem.dQ3}</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:right;">${listItem.qty3}</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:right;">${listItem.dQ4}</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:right;">${listItem.qty4}</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:right;">${listItem.dQ5}</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:right;">${listItem.qty5}</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:right;">${listItem.dQ6}</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:right;">${listItem.qty6}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                        </c:forEach>
                                    </c:if>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </c:if>
                            <c:if test="${empty  dataList}">
                            <tr align="center">
                                <font color="red">No Data Found !!!</font>
                            <tr>
                        </c:if>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                        </table>
```

Comment: If you are sending request through Ajax, YOU MUST manipulate the data in the ajax success function not in jsp or through jstl. Load dynamically inside success function